# ReactJS—Child Component does not unmount

Tags: reactjs

I have created a wrapper component, which can be configured with another Component, to share some functionality. Basically the wrapper Component creates a new DomNode and renders the the child component from its props like so:

```
//wrapper
componentDidMount () {
  this.node = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
}

componentDidUpdate () {
  if (this.state.editing) {
    ReactDOM.render(this.props.component, this.node);
  } else {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.node)
  }
}

//component from within the props of the wrapper above
componentWillUnmount () { /* runs */ }

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      <AnotherThing />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**BUT** `componentWillUnmount()` of the instance of `<AnotherThing />` never triggers. Is that the default, or am I wrong here? I would expect `componentWillUnmount()` to be triggered for all components in the subtree.

**UPDATE**

This is all working as it should. My watch process stopped working, that is why I could not see the unmounting.

Comment: Why exactly are you using ReactDOM inside of your component? I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but many use cases can be covered either by selective rendering in the render function or by higher order components

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve what you want way easier than you are doing it right now.

Your render function could look like this:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div>
      { this.state.editing ? this.props.component : null }
    </div>
  )
}
```

`render` will run when your state or your props are changing, so you do not need separate life-cycle methods to achieve what you want to achieve. React will take care of mounting and umounting the `this.props.component`.

Comment: that would render `this.props.component` into the same DOMNode of the wrapper, but that should be in another one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want your component to modify the DOM itself, adding another component somewhere in the DOM? This seems like a very bad idea and goes against the concept of React. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: But that what I am doing and is working quite well for now. I have multiple mount points, it only adds the additional work of mounting and unmount those »child components«

Comment: @phillip Following the conversation I think your understanding of the basic react principles is a little off. Have a look at the official documentation for conditional rendering: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: @Spoke Well, I know those things, but in that very Situation I have to push a bit beyond the principles and best-practices… However, its working fine, it was the watch process that stopped to work…